# Do URL Tracking parameters used on internal links override the inital Google Analytics traffic sources?

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, traffic, url-parameters, goal-tracking

To test the success of various banners and CTA images that we have put across multiple pages on our website, we are tagging them with URL builders' parameters to track the source, medium and campaign. We have also enabled Goals to track the sign up form submissions.

If a user comes as an organic traffi c(eg: from google search) and visits our website and then clicks on any of the images on our website having URL builders' parameters enabled(source,medium and campaign), then does this override the analytics' parameters? Will this count as an organic search or under the source/medium parameters that I have defined using URL Builder?

If the analytics' data is getting overridden by our URL Builders' parameters then what is the other way to track visitor clicks on our website to measure the success of our banners and images?

Answer (score 2):

Using GA Campaign tagging on internal links is not recommended as they will override the original source/medium of the visitor.

There are so many ways this can be done.
The quickest/easiest to get up and running with would be event tracking.

Clicks to links would usually be tracked via event tracking triggered by an onclick. 
Banner/image 'impressions' could also be tracked as events triggered by onload rather than onclick.

Keep in mind events can also be tracked in GA as goals, however if you are wanting to track them as steps within a goal funnel, then a virtual pageview will need to be tracked instead of an event.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

Comment: This answer is accurate. Another important reason why you should not use "UTM Tags" is because they are mainly used to tags campaign and track external traffic derived from a specific campaign, every time an user clicks the link text/images with the parameters is basically sending a source reference generating a new session every time an user clicks. Expect an artificial increase in number of sessions which is wrong if the user has been in your website for less than 30min (default session duration)